# phpword подсчет слов

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

Как с помощью библиотеки phpword подсчитать слова в документе?

Comment: ссылку на библиотеку дайте

Answer (score 1):

Возможно ваша библиотека не поддерживает такой функции. Могу предложить решение встроенной функцией php: [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-word-count.php)

```
$string = 'Любое предложение или простая строка.';
echo str_word_count ($string, 0); // Количество слов.
```